# Laravel 5.4 change $redirectTo value in built in log in to session value

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Working with `Laravel 5.4` and I am using the built in authentication process.

I want to change this dynamically:

```
/**
 * URI where we redirect to after registration
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = 'player/home';
```

Like this:

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    if (session()->has('game.details.redirect')) {
        $this->redirectTo = session()->get('game.details.redirect');
    }
}
```

But the above does not work as I cannot access `$this` in static method. How do I achieve this assignment every time the controller is accessed?

Answer (score 3):

You can define the function `redirectTo` instead of the property in `loginController`.

As Laravel doc says:

> If the redirect path needs custom generation logic you may define a redirectTo method instead of a  redirectTo property

```
    function redirectTo(){
       if (session()->has('game.details.redirect')) {
            return session()->get('game.details.redirect');
       }
    }
```

And, it is also the more preferred method.

> The redirectTo method will take precedence over the redirectTo attribute.

Read more about it here : [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-authenticating)

Hope it answers your question.